# Speaker for crystal radio rather than sensitive piezoelectric speaker Crystal radio

Tags: radio, crystal

I am a science student of grade 8 and  researching and learning about radio waves.

I am currently trying to make a crystal radio. The problem I am facing is  the speaker I have to use for the project.

I searched on the internet regarding the same and found that there are high sensitive piezoelectric earpiece that most of the people use for  crystal radios, but in my locality I could not find them.

So I also tried using piezoelectric buzzer for my project but it failed to produce sound.

what kind of speaker should I use?

Comment: so, what is "your locality"? Although probably not in production anymore, you can still buy millions of these things e.g. on ebay or on Chinese seller sites, so that'd be my solution – unless you're in a country where China doesn't ship to, but a) not quite sure that's likely and b) in that case, any other solution might be even harder to acquire.

Comment: Unfortunately, a crystal radio provides very little power to the earpiece. That's why the small earpieces are usually used...you don't really have other options.

Comment: Unlike the comments I see so far, there is a lot of science to designing and maximizing the performance of a crystal radio. It's a complete system. And each and every piece of it counts and matters. None of it can be ignored, or isolated. Everything from the tuning coil, to the detector diode, and on over to the earpiece and finally to your ear drum --- all of it must be matched in order to maximize sensitivity. Before I go further, are you allowed to use battery power at all? Or must this be entirely self-powered from what's picked up over the airwaves?

Answer (score 1):

You might try looking in old Army surplus stores. Old tube type radios used a 2000 ohm headphone. This is the type of headphone that was used on crystal radios in the past century.

The impedance is 2000 ohms, and the resistance is a bit lower. Take an ohmmeter along with you shopping so you can measure the headphone. Anything measuring from 500 to 2000 ohms could work.

You can also search online for 2000 ohm headphone.

Answer (score 0):

You say you tried a piezo buzzer that has a transistor oscillator inside to make it beep. Instead you should try a piezo transducer (speaker).

Answer (score 0):

Piezo Buzzer :
Just remove all the electronic parts and use only the thin flat round  diaphragm. 
Watch the wires though. Dont pull them off from the flat round disc.
The diaphragm is a brass plate (-ve) on which a thin layer of glassy piezo material (+ve).
This is the Piezo speaker/ transducer.